# C++ undefined reference to `__imp_StretchDIBits'

Tags: c++

I am using Windows, and following a [video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PJmpOhk9GXw&list=PL7Ej6SUky135IAAR3PFCFyiVwanauRqj3&index=3) to learn how to create a window in C++. I am new to the concept and to developing in general. (I know whaching YT vidéo isn't always the best but i don't know where to learn that, if somme of u could help me, even finding a best tutorial)

I include `<windows.h>`, but on the call of the function `StretchDIBits()`, the compiler return an error:

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\(my user name)\AppData\Local\Temp\ccxbyGSE.o:win32_Platform:(.text+0x315): undefined reference to `__imp_StretchDIBits'
```

Here's the code:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
bool running = true;

void *buffer_memory;
int buffer_width;
int buffer_heigth;

BITMAPINFO buffer_bitmap_info;

LRESULT CALLBACK window_callback(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    LRESULT result = 0;

    switch (uMsg){
        case WM_CLOSE:
        case WM_DESTROY:{
            running = false;
        }break;
        case WM_SIZE:{

            RECT rect;
            GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
            buffer_width = rect.right - rect.left;
            buffer_heigth = rect.bottom - rect.top;

            int buffer_size = buffer_width * buffer_heigth * sizeof(unsigned int);
            if(buffer_memory) VirtualFree(buffer_memory, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
            buffer_memory = VirtualAlloc(0,buffer_size,MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);

            buffer_bitmap_info.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(buffer_bitmap_info.bmiHeader);
            buffer_bitmap_info.bmiHeader.biWidth = buffer_width;
            buffer_bitmap_info.bmiHeader.biHeight = buffer_heigth;
            buffer_bitmap_info.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
            buffer_bitmap_info.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
            buffer_bitmap_info.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
            
        }break;

        default:{
            result = DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }
    return result;
}


int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,LPSTR lpCmdLine,int nShowCmd){

    // créé une classe fenêtre
    WNDCLASS window_class = {};
    window_class.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    window_class.lpszClassName = "Game Window class";
    window_class.lpfnWndProc = window_callback;
    //Register Class
    RegisterClass(&window_class);

    //créé une fenêtre

    HWND window = CreateWindow(window_class.lpszClassName, "Ce qu'il y a en haut de la fenêtre", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, CW_USEDEFAULT ,CW_USEDEFAULT, 1280,720,0,0, hInstance,0);
    HDC hdc = GetDC(window);

    while(running){
        //Entré
        MSG message;
        while( PeekMessage(&message, window, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) ) {
            TranslateMessage(&message);
            DispatchMessage(&message);
        }
        //Simuler

        //Rendue
        StretchDIBits(hdc,0,0,buffer_width,buffer_heigth,0,0,buffer_width, buffer_heigth,buffer_memory,&buffer_bitmap_info,DIB_RGB_COLORS,SRCCOPY);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting to get back a window.

Comment: The windows API is very painful to learn as a newcomer. I highly recommend you check out Qt which is C++-centric.

Comment: To answer your question, if you search for the function name [StretchDIBits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-stretchdibits) the Microsoft documentation tells you which library to link to. It is `Gdi32.lib`.

Comment: *I am folowing a vidéo on YT* is often the start of the problem. Be really careful you're not being fed garbage by some content farming <expletive deleted> who only cares that you stick around for the ads and view-count and has absolutely no interest in whether or not you learned anything useful.

Comment: @Blarze You are getting a LINKER error, not a COMPILER error.  The COMPILER knows you are *calling* `StretchDIBits()` and generates appropriate code for that, but the LINKER isn't able to match up that call to the *implementation* for that function, hence the error. You need to *link* to the library that implements the `StretchDIBits()` function, which is `gdi32.dll`, so you need to link your project to your compiler's version of `gdi32.lib`.

Comment: There are thousands of tutorials about the low-level way to do windows on Windows. And any of them that doesn't use global variables are much better than the video you're watching.

Comment: And many tutorials, apparently the one you're using as well, teach the C-way to use the Windows API. There's not an ounce of C++ in the code you show. It's basically a C program.

Answer (score 1):

> You are getting a LINKER error, not a COMPILER error. The COMPILER knows you are *calling* `StretchDIBits()` and generates appropriate code for that, but the LINKER isn't able to match up that call to the *implementation* for that function, hence the error. You need to `link` to the library that implements the `StretchDIBits()` function, which is `gdi32.dll`, so you need to link your project to your compiler's version of `gdi32.lib`.

–
Remy Lebeau